# Searchlogic on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, searchlogic

I have the following associations:

```
class BookShelf {
  has_many :books
}

class Book {
  has_many :pages
  belongs_to :book_shelf
}

class Page {
  belongs_to :book
}
```

If I have a BookShelf object, how could I use searchlogic to search pages that belong to the books in the current book shelf?

Currently I'm using this one:

```
@bookshelf = BookShelf.find 1
@pages = Page.title_like("something").book_id_equals(@bookshelf.books.map { |book| book.id }).paginate :page => params[:page]
```

So the paginate part is just the use of will_paginate which is not really relavent.

The point is I think these lines of codes are somewhat ugly. Is there any improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, and remove the need to map all the book ids into an array:

```
Page.title_like("something").book_bookshelf_id_equals(@bookshelf.id).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

I tested it in one of my apps, where I had a similar model structure (Suburb -> Region -> State) using the following:

```
Suburb.name_like("east").region_state_name_like("vi").paginate(:page => 3)
```

Which seemed to do the trick.